# Create a markdown unordered list from a string

Tags: markdown, react-markdown

I have a text column in our database(postgresql if that matters) that is then rendered using markdown. I want that text column to represent an unordered list, which means I need to somehow add a linebreak(\n) inside my string to workaround that. Ive tried this answer: [Mimic a newline in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212168/mimic-a-newline-in-markdown) with no success, the markdown string ive entered is:

```
- One  \n- Two  \n- Three  \n- Four
```

and the rendered output is:

[image]

The markdown is rendered using a react library called "simple-markdown"
any idea how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is compatible with some markdown tools.

```html
<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li></ul>
```

Output:

- One
- Two
- Three
- Four